# Gradle build runss androidTest

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

Using gradle 2.2.1 and com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0

When I run `./gradle build` in the console the build fails at step `:testDebugUnitTest`.

It fails because it tries to run a `InstrumentationTestCase` that should not happen.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

This is normal. It's because `build` depends on other tasks. You can see these tasks by running `gradle tasks --all`.

For `build` it will show this: `build - Assembles and tests this project. [assemble, check]`.

The `check` task is configured like this: `check - Runs all checks. [assembleDebug, lint, test]`

The `test` task like this: `test - Run unit tests for all variants. [testDebugUnitTest, testReleaseUnitTest]`

And that is why you see the `testDebugUnitTest` show up when you run the `build` task.

So if you just want to build without testing, you need to run `gradle assemble`. And if you want to save time and only build the variant you need, you can run `gradle assembleDebug`, for example.

Comment: Thank you, I understand this part, what I don't understand is why `:testDebugUnitTest` is running instrumentationTests

Comment: What is your folder structure like? Do you have both a `test` and `androidTest` folder? Do you have any `InstrumentationTestCase` in the `test` folder?

Comment: I have both test and androidTest, and of course no InstrumentationTestCase in the test folder, the build passes on the CI so it must be something in my env. Will reinstall all and check again.